# ! Argument of \readlist_vii has an extra }

Tags: errors, texlive-2016

I have a LaTeX document which can be compiled by MiKTeX on my system without any problem. When I upload the document and its corresponding dependent files to ArXiv, it throws the following error compiled by TeX Live 2016:

```
! Argument of \readlist_vii has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.147 \end{equation}

? 
! Emergency stop.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.147 \end{equation}

! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

The cited `equation` environment is indeed associated with the following snippet:

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq:kin}
\bm{q^{i}} = \bm{q^{i}_{b}} + 
\bracketMatrixstack{\cos{(\theta^{i})} & \cos{(\theta^{i} + \phi^{i})}\\
    \sin{(\theta^{i})} & \sin{(\theta^{i} + \phi^{i})}} \bm{l}
\end{equation}
```

Moreover, the following setting drives `\bracketMatrixstack` command:

```
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\setstacktabbedgap{1.5ex}
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\normalbaselineskip}
\def\stackalignment{c}
```

Given the following `MWE` (I just copied the whole preamble as it may convey some extra information about the issue):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{spieman} 

\pdfoutput=1

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

 %for \bracketMatrixstack and/or \bracketVectorstack%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\setstacktabbedgap{1.5ex}%               sets gap between columns
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\normalbaselineskip}% sets baselineskip of rows
\def\stackalignment{c}%                  sets column alignment
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document} 

\section{Introduction}
\begin{equation}
\bm{q^{i}} = \bm{q^{i}_{b}} + 
\bracketMatrixstack{\cos{(\theta^{i})} & \cos{(\theta^{i} + \phi^{i})}\\
    \sin{(\theta^{i})} & \sin{(\theta^{i} + \phi^{i})}} \bm{l}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

What does TeX Live complain about here?

**Edit 1:** the result using `\bmatrix` environment is (IMO) not that much eye-catching (in view of those excessively-long brackets):

[image]

**Edit 2:** the [spieman](https://www.spiedigitallibrary.org/documents/Journals/spie-journal-papers-latex.zip) class can be found here. (The link is copied from [SPIE](https://www.spiedigitallibrary.org/journals/journal-of-astronomical-telescopes-instruments-and-systems/author-guidelines) website.)

Comment: we can't debug fragments please post a proper test

Comment: I tried to add a suitable preamble; I get no error using TL from 2013 to 2020. By the way, what's the reason for not using a simple `bmatrix` environment?

Comment: @egreg: Please have a look at the `Edit` part of the question.

Comment: is that really the smallest example that you could make??? In any case It gives an error on line 1 in texlive. as that class is not installed. Please post a _reasonable_ example that shows the problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I had explained why I did consider the whole preamble. Now, it is indeed an `MWE`.

Comment: It's still using a non standard class I don't have

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Please check the presented link in the Edit 2.

Comment: can you not show the problem using article class?  I'm not keen on having to follow a link to some unknown site and unzip a zip. If it is only a problem which shows with that class it's a commercial class supported by a publisher so you should first ask them to fix it. But it's easy for you to see if the problem also occurs with article class

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: The link is borrowed from here which is a well-known publisher's website: https://www.spiedigitallibrary.org/journals/journal-of-astronomical-telescopes-instruments-and-systems/author-guidelines. The problem only shows up if one uses this class, and `article` class does not reflect anything. I don't know whether this is a problem because of a mistake of mine or with the class to ask the publisher for any fix.

Comment: I get no error from your code. And if I use `bmatrix` I get an even better result than with `\bracketMatrixstack`. Please, make sure that the code ***does*** produce the error.

Comment: @egreg: I have copied the error from the log file of the ArXiv website (which is run based on TeX Live 2016, as they have declared). Thanks, anyway.